# Check if an array of an array contains a certain string

Tags: php, arrays

I'm checking to make sure an array of arrays does not contain certain strings before adding any new child arrays to the parent array

I want to make sure that if an array with the same `website` and `condition` exists a new child array will not be added to the parent array.

**e.g.** in this example the `$newArr` must not be inserted in to the array `$arr` because their already exists an array with the same `website` and `condition`.

```
$arr = array(
   array(
      'website' => 'amazon',
      'price' => 20,
      'location' => 'uk',
      'link' => '...',
      'condition' => 'new'
   ),
   array(
      'website' => 'abe',
      'price' => 20,
      'location' => 'uk',
      'link' => '...',
      'condition' => 'new'
   )
);

$newArr = array(
      'website' => 'amazon',
      'price' => 60,
      'location' => 'uk',
      'link' => '...',
      'condition' => 'new'
   )
```

I'm looking for an easy solution as using the function `in_array` on the parent array is not enough.

**code so far**

```
$arr = array();

foreach($table->find('tr.result') as $row){

   if(($website = $row->find('a img',0)) 
      && ($price = $row->find('span.results-price a',0))
      && ($location = $row->find('.results-explanatory-text-Logo'))                     
      && ($link = $row->find('a',0))){                  

      $website = str_replace( array('.gif','.jpg','.png'), '', basename($website->src));
      $price = floatval(trim(str_replace(',', '', $price->innertext), "&pound;")); 
      $location = "uk";         
      $link = $link->href;

      $arr[] = array(
         'website' => $website,
         'price' => $price,
         'location' => $location,
         'link' => $link,
         'condition' => 'new'
      );
   }            
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You loop over `$arr` each time to look for `$website` and `$condition` (always `'new'`?) or you can keep a secondary array of the found keys. If you're starting with an empty `$arr` each time, the second approach will work and be faster.

```
$arr = array();
$keys = array();

foreach($table->find('tr.result') as $row){

   if(...){                  
      ...
      $condition = 'new'; // set as needed

      // track seen keys
      $key = $website . '|' . $condition; // assumes neither field contains '|'
      if (!isset($keys[$key])) {
         $keys[$key] = true;
         $arr[] = array(...);
      }
   }            
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope the comments in the below code speak for themselves... I'm not a PHP pro, and this is probably not the most elegant way, but I believe the logic makes sense. Obviously the $new_array object has some variables that aren't declared but it's for example only.

I hope that helps and that no one down votes me :)

```
<?php
    // Original array
    $arr = array();

    foreach($result as $row) {
        // Get the new array as an object first so we can check whether to add to the loop
        $new_array = array(
            'website' => $website,
            'price' => $price,
            'location' => $location,
            'link' => $link,
            'condition' => 'new'
        );

        // If the original array is empty there's no point in looping through it
        if(!empty($arr)) {
            foreach($arr as $child) {
                // Check through each item of the original array
                foreach($new_array as $compare) {
                    // Compare each item in the new array against the original array
                    if(in_array($compare, $child)) {
                        // if there's a match, the new array will not get added
                        continue;
                    }
                }

            }   
        }

            // If there's no match, the new array gets added
        $arr[] = $new_array;
    }
?>
```

Comment: looks like a standard search, not elegant but I will probably use this if nothing else comes up

Comment: You're comparing only the values, so two different keys that map to the same value will trigger a "match", though unlikely given that each type of element is pretty distinct. But more importantly, `continue` will have zero effect there since it's the last statement of the enclosing `foreeach` loop. Thus `$new_array` will be added to `$arr` every time.